# Unable to login with ldapuser

Tags: ldap, centos7, openldap, pam-ldap

I have configured openldap with back-sql on ubuntu 18.04 but unable to login with ldapusers on client machine (centos 7). I am able to fetch user details using **ldapsearch** command on client machine but login is not happening. I am getting "User does not exists" error while login.

Please find the below output of ldapsearch command.

```
[root@ldapclient ~]# ldapsearch -x -b "dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com"
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (objectclass=*)
# requesting: ALL
#

# mrugesh, mobilewaretech.com
dn: cn=mrugesh,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
seeAlso: documentTitle=book1,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
seeAlso: documentTitle=book2,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
givenName: mrugesh
userPassword:: cXdlcnR5MTIz
telephoneNumber: 222-3234
telephoneNumber: 332-2334

# amey, mobilewaretech.com
dn: cn=amey,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
seeAlso: documentTitle=book1,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
givenName: amey
userPassword:: YW1leQ==
telephoneNumber: 545-4563

# Kishor Toraskar, mobilewaretech.com
dn: cn=Kishor Toraskar,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: pkiUser
cn: Kishor Toraskar
sn: Toraskar
givenName: Kishor
userCertificate;binary:: MIIDazCCAtSgAwIBAgIBAjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQQFADB3MQswCQYDV
 QQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2FsaWZvcm5pYTEfMB0GA1UEChMWT3BlbkxEQVAgRXhhbXBsZSwgTH
 RkLjETMBEGA1UEAxMKRXhhbXBsZSBDQTEdMBsGCSqGSIb3DQEJARYOY2FAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20wHhc
 NMDMxMDE3MTYzMzE5WhcNMDQxMDE2MTYzMzE5WjB+MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzETMBEGA1UECBMKQ2Fs
 aWZvcm5pYTEfMB0GA1UEChMWT3BlbkxEQVAgRXhhbXBsZSwgTHRkLjEYMBYGA1UEAxMPVXJzdWxhI
 EhhbXBzdGVyMR8wHQYJKoZIhvcNAQkBFhB1aGFtQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tMIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQ
 UAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDuxgp5ELV9LmhxWMpV7qc4028QQT3+zzFDXhruuXE7ji2n3S3ea8bOwDtJh+q
 nsDe561DhHHHlgIjMKCiDEizYMpxvJPYEXmvp0huRkMgpKZgmel95BSkt6TYmJ0erS3aoimOHLEFi
 mmnTLolNRMiWqNBvqwobx940PGwUWEePKQIDAQABo4H/MIH8MAkGA1UdEwQCMAAwLAYJYIZIAYb4Q
 gENBB8WHU9wZW5TU0wgR2VuZXJhdGVkIENlcnRpZmljYXRlMB0GA1UdDgQWBBSjI94TbBmuDEeUUO
 iC37EK0Uf0XjCBoQYDVR0jBIGZMIGWgBRLbyEaNiTSkPlDsFNHLX3hwOaYI6F7pHkwdzELMAkGA1U
 EBhMCVVMxEzARBgNVBAgTCkNhbGlmb3JuaWExHzAdBgNVBAoTFk9wZW5MREFQIEV4YW1wbGUsIEx0
 ZC4xEzARBgNVBAMTCkV4YW1wbGUgQ0ExHTAbBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWDmNhQGV4YW1wbGUuY29tggEAM
 A0GCSqGSIb3DQEBBAUAA4GBAIgUcARb3OlWYNbmr1nmqESuxLn16uqI1Ot6WkcICvpkdQ+Bo+R9AP
 05xpoXocZtKdNvBu3FNxB/jFkiOcLU2lX7Px1Ijnsjh60qVRy9HOsHCungIKlGcnXLKHmKu0y//5j
 ds/HnaJsGcHI5JRG7CBJbW+wrwge3trJ1xHJI8prN

# book1, mobilewaretech.com
dn: documentTitle=book1,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: document
description: abstract1
documentTitle: book1
documentAuthor: cn=amey,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
documentAuthor: cn=mrugesh,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
documentIdentifier: document 1

# book2, mobilewaretech.com
dn: documentTitle=book2,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: document
description: abstract2
documentTitle: book2
documentAuthor: cn=mrugesh,dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
documentIdentifier: document 2

# mobilewaretech.com
dn: dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com
objectClass: organization
objectClass: dcObject
o: Mobileware
dc: mobileware

# search reference
ref: ldap://localhost:389/dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com??sub

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 8
# numEntries: 6
# numReferences: 1
```

I have referred this https://gist.github.com/mahirrudin/9b7754e54f1e8e532049484864beba42 URL for configuring the openldap server with back-sql. Here's my nsswitch.conf file from client machine.

```
#
# /etc/nsswitch.conf
#
# An example Name Service Switch config file. This file should be
# sorted with the most-used services at the beginning.
#
# The entry '[NOTFOUND=return]' means that the search for an
# entry should stop if the search in the previous entry turned
# up nothing. Note that if the search failed due to some other reason
# (like no NIS server responding) then the search continues with the
# next entry.
#
# Valid entries include:
#
#       nisplus                 Use NIS+ (NIS version 3)
#       nis                     Use NIS (NIS version 2), also called YP
#       dns                     Use DNS (Domain Name Service)
#       files                   Use the local files
#       db                      Use the local database (.db) files
#       compat                  Use NIS on compat mode
#       hesiod                  Use Hesiod for user lookups
#       [NOTFOUND=return]       Stop searching if not found so far
#

# To use db, put the "db" in front of "files" for entries you want to be
# looked up first in the databases
#
# Example:
#passwd:    db files nisplus nis
#shadow:    db files nisplus nis
#group:     db files nisplus nis

passwd:     mysql files sss
shadow:     mysql files sss
group:      mysql files sss
#initgroups: files sss

#hosts:     db files nisplus nis dns
hosts:      files dns myhostname

# Example - obey only what nisplus tells us...
#services:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#networks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#protocols:  nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#rpc:        nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#ethers:     nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files
#netmasks:   nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

bootparams: nisplus [NOTFOUND=return] files

ethers:     files
netmasks:   files
networks:   files
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files sss

netgroup:   files sss

publickey:  nisplus

automount:  files sss
aliases:    files nisplus
```

Please find nslcd.conf file.

## This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice

## switch library's nslcd daemon. It configures the mapping

## between NSS names (see /etc/nsswitch.conf) and LDAP

## information in the directory.

## See the manual page nslcd.conf(5) for more information.

## The user and group nslcd should run as.

uid nslcd
gid ldap

## The uri pointing to the LDAP server to use for name lookups.

## Multiple entries may be specified. The address that is used

## here should be resolvable without using LDAP (obviously).

## uri ldap://127.0.0.1/

## uri ldaps://127.0.0.1/

## uri ldapi://%2fvar%2frun%2fldapi_sock/

## Note: %2f encodes the '/' used as directory separator

uri ldap://192.168.0.227:389/

## The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3

## if supported by client library)

## ldap_version 3

## The distinguished name of the search base.

base dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com

## The distinguished name to bind to the server with.

## Optional: default is to bind anonymously.

## binddn cn=proxyuser,dc=example,dc=com

## The credentials to bind with.

## Optional: default is no credentials.

## Note that if you set a bindpw you should check the permissions of this file.

## bindpw secret

## The distinguished name to perform password modifications by root by.

## rootpwmoddn cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

## The default search scope.

## scope sub

## scope one

## scope base

## Customize certain database lookups.

## base   group  ou=Groups,dc=example,dc=com

## base   passwd ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

## base   shadow ou=People,dc=example,dc=com

## scope  group  onelevel

## scope  hosts  sub

## Bind/connect timelimit.

## bind_timelimit 30

## Search timelimit.

## timelimit 30

## Idle timelimit. nslcd will close connections if the

## server has not been contacted for the number of seconds.

## idle_timelimit 3600

## Use StartTLS without verifying the server certificate.

## ssl start_tls

## tls_reqcert never

## CA certificates for server certificate verification

## tls_cacertdir /etc/ssl/certs

## tls_cacertfile /etc/ssl/ca.cert

## Seed the PRNG if /dev/urandom is not provided

## tls_randfile /var/run/egd-pool

## SSL cipher suite

## See man ciphers for syntax

## tls_ciphers TLSv1

## Client certificate and key

## Use these, if your server requires client authentication.

## tls_cert

## tls_key

## Mappings for Services for UNIX 3.5

## filter passwd (objectClass=User)

## map    passwd uid              msSFU30Name

## map    passwd userPassword     msSFU30Password

## map    passwd homeDirectory    msSFU30HomeDirectory

## map    passwd homeDirectory    msSFUHomeDirectory

## filter shadow (objectClass=User)

## map    shadow uid              msSFU30Name

## map    shadow userPassword     msSFU30Password

## filter group  (objectClass=Group)

## map    group  member           msSFU30PosixMember

## Mappings for Services for UNIX 2.0

## filter passwd (objectClass=User)

## map    passwd uid              msSFUName

## map    passwd userPassword     msSFUPassword

## map    passwd homeDirectory    msSFUHomeDirectory

## map    passwd gecos            msSFUName

## filter shadow (objectClass=User)

## map    shadow uid              msSFUName

## map    shadow userPassword     msSFUPassword

## map    shadow shadowLastChange pwdLastSet

## filter group  (objectClass=Group)

## map    group  member           posixMember

## Mappings for Active Directory

## pagesize 1000

## referrals off

## idle_timelimit 800

## filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))

## map    passwd uid              sAMAccountName

## map    passwd homeDirectory    unixHomeDirectory

## map    passwd gecos            displayName

## filter shadow (&(objectClass=user)(!(objectClass=computer))(uidNumber=*)(unixHomeDirectory=*))

## map    shadow uid              sAMAccountName

## map    shadow shadowLastChange pwdLastSet

## filter group  (objectClass=group)

## Alternative mappings for Active Directory

## (replace the SIDs in the objectSid mappings with the value for your domain)

## pagesize 1000

## referrals off

## idle_timelimit 800

## filter passwd (&(objectClass=user)(objectClass=person)(!(objectClass=computer)))

## map    passwd uid           cn

## map    passwd uidNumber     objectSid:S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820

## map    passwd gidNumber     objectSid:S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820

## map    passwd homeDirectory "/home/$cn"

## map    passwd gecos         displayName

## map    passwd loginShell    "/bin/bash"

## filter group (|(objectClass=group)(objectClass=person))

## map    group gidNumber      objectSid:S-1-5-21-3623811015-3361044348-30300820

## Mappings for AIX SecureWay

## filter passwd (objectClass=aixAccount)

## map    passwd uid              userName

## map    passwd userPassword     passwordChar

## map    passwd uidNumber        uid

## map    passwd gidNumber        gid

## filter group  (objectClass=aixAccessGroup)

## map    group  cn               groupName

## map    group  gidNumber        gid

## This comment prevents repeated auto-migration of settings.

ssl no
tls_cacertdir /etc/openldap/cacerts

Comment: Please provide your configuration for ldap login on your client.

Comment: [root@ldapclient ~]# cat /etc/nslcd.conf
# This is the configuration file for the LDAP nameservice
# switch library's nslcd daemon. It configures the mapping
# between NSS names (see /etc/nsswitch.conf) and LDAP

# The user and group nslcd should run as.
uid nslcd
gid ldap

uri ldap://192.168.0.227:389/

# The LDAP version to use (defaults to 3
# if supported by client library)
#ldap_version 3

# The distinguished name of the search base.
base dc=mobilewaretech,dc=com

Comment: Please don't add further information in comments, it's unreadable here. Edit your question instead. Log entries from your login attempts are also useful.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider I'm sorry. I am a new user so I was not aware. Will take care in future. Thanks!

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Please help.

Comment: In order for anyone to help you, please do as Gerald asked - edit the question (using the "Edit" link below the question) to include the contents of `/etc/nslcd.conf`, and also the log entries from your failed login attempts.When you edit the question, it will be automatically put in the reopen queue and if it now contains enough information for people to be able to help you, it will be reopened.

Answer (score 1):

These users lack necessary fields for being able to log in.

```
uidNumber:
gidNumber:
loginShell:
homeDirectory:
userPassword:
```

This attributes are a standard part of `objectClass: posixAccount`.

Also, you should look to your `/etc/nsswitch.conf` as is it may not have ldap as a  source.

Comment: I have added the contents of /etc/nsswitch.conf file in question. Please check.